# Memcached incr/decr limits

Tags: memcached

According to https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L309, numbers manipulated with incr and decr "will wrap around the 64 bit mark".

1) Since the lower limit appears to be 0, does that mean the highest possible value is 18446744073709551615, or would it be 9223372036854775807?

2) Is that the limit on both 32 bit and 64 bit operating systems? Would the limit of incr/decr be 4294967295 instead on 32 bit OS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The lower limit is 0 and the upper limit is 2^64.

2) Cas is held as a uint64_t so this means that the cas should be 64 bits on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.